# Backend not open and frontend is working fine in magento1.9.0.0

Tags: admin

admin panel not loading and front end is working fine in magento1.9

Please check screenshot

[image]

Comment: what you are getting when you try to access backend ? if possible share screen shot

Comment: flush your magento root /var/cache folder and /var/session folders, It may have previous server session that may cause problems.
Otherwise disable all third party modules and try again. I think this will help

Comment: Try to give more information about the context of the problem. What do you see, any errors? Was it working before? Is it a new installation or exsisting one? The more information you provide the better (and faster) other people can help you. PS: Welcome to the community =)

Answer (score 0):

Open your phpmyadmin from your host try once this sql command.
Run this Sql

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE core_store SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE core_store_group SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE core_website SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin'; 
UPDATE customer_group SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Now admin can able to login.
please follow this [admin page shows 404 page not found](http://tejabhagavan.blogspot.in/2015/12/after-install-magento-admin-page-shows.html)